# Convert ONE two-dimensional array into TWO one-dimensional arrays

Tags: c#, java, arrays, algorithm

You may feel weird about what I'm asking, but it's true, convert 1 `two-dimensional array` into ***2*** `one-dimensional arrays`.

That was what my teacher asked, and he said he would give a perfect point for whoever answers this (I think, tricky) question. I would happy to convert any 2 or n-dimensional array into one one-dimensional array. But he said 2, so I think there must be something to do with the second array. And, he didn't tell what type of array (int, String or object), so I assume it must be done with any kind of 2-dimensional array.

This is what I will answer him if no one here figure out what he wants: Convert into a 1-dimensional array, and leave the second null (or let it have no element). But I don't think it's a good answer for such a tricky question.

**EDIT:** Here is my teacher question, word-by-word (he just ask at the end of the session in voice, not in the textbook, as a bonus question(with... a nice bonus reward)): Given **a** `2-dimensional array`, convert it into **two** `1-dimensional array`s.

I don't know if [][] in Java and C# considered `2-dimensional array`, but C# does have [, ], which is 2-dimensional array. We are studying computer algorithm, with no target IDE or language.

**EDIT2:** I emailed him, and he refused to give additional information (he said it was unfair for others if I have more information than them), and he didn't give any comments about jagged array idea. The only useful thing in his reply: Let [][] be considered `2-dimensional array`.

Comment: Given that Java doesn't really *have* two-dimensional arrays as such (it has arrays of arrays) it's hard to give a good answer. It really helps to have a precise question - ideally with sample input and expected output. I don't think the question is necessary "tricky" as "not well-specified".

Comment: This sounds more like a lateral thinking puzzle than a coding problem. i.e. what trick is he using that makes what he's said make sense once you are given a bit of extra info.

Comment: Could you post (or link to) the exact wording of the instructor's question?

Comment: I guess the idea is to be able to convert the 2 one-dimensional arrays back to the 'original' - what I would do is to 'flatten' the original array into one dimensional array and remember the "points of the appending" in the second array

Comment: I think this below post helps your

Comment: Bond's answer would perfect fit if that was case "array of arrays". You may think of cases, where it would be suitable to keep some neighbor information or additional information in second array, but without context it is hard to tell.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just edited my post. The question is not from any textbook, just a question he asked by mouth at the end of the class. I tried to give you every word he said.

Comment: @W.N.: Then I'm afraid the question is just too poorly phrased to have a meaningful definitive answer. Press your teacher for more details next time :)

Comment: I believe that the answer we're pretty much all consistent on still works (even with jagged arrays, as George Duckett points out). And [][] implements the 2-dimensional array concept just fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I have 2 days left to answer this question, and I won't meet him until then. Next time, I will sure press him on the bonus questions. But maybe, according to the answers below, he meant jagged arrays.

Comment: One idea would be in one array keep row by row and in second column by column, some imaging algoritm that works in two passes (first pass horizontal, second vertical) may have use from this, I think that would be more logical explanation, than save indices of row starts (because you can calculate them very easy).

Comment: @W.N.: Can you email him to get more details?

Comment: @JonSkeet I will. Maybe he will give more details, but I think it will take long, about at least 12 hours, because it's mid-night here.
To Giedrius: Very logical! So I think of 2 possibilities: Jagged array & your theory. But I think I have to choose one.

Comment: @JonSkeet I emailed him, just edited the question.

Comment: That seems like no change in scenario. One could argue that any solution that satisfies the minimal criteria would be correct. Without knowing his intentions, you have several good choices below that should work.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for all your support, I got the perfect point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten the 2-d array in either row-major or column-major order, storing it in one of the 1-d arrays. Store the shape `{n, m}` of the array in the other 1-d integer array. Given the indices for an element in the 2-d array of values, you can use the shape to calculate the index in the 1-d array of values.

The two representations are isomorphic, and both allow looking up the values in constant time. It's also similar to how a 2-d array is represented in memory.

Comment: You're welcome! If you wrote any code to demonstrate the approach, I hope you'll edit it in for anyone who sees your question in the future.

Answer (score 6):

I'll bite. It's possible to flatten the entire two-dimensional array into the first of the two one-dimensional arrays by simply reading and writing consistently. I.e. store row 1 then row 2, etc. sequentially in that first array. Whenever you move to the next row, store the index of that next cell (of the first one dimensional array) in the second one-dimensional array, which would essentially become a row index table.

As Jon Skeet said above, this isn't a very well-specified question; perhaps with clarified information, we could better help you.

Comment: Might be worth noting the 2nd array isn't required for a 2D array (as row lengths are constant), but it would be required for a jagged array.

Comment: you don't need the array of row indices since that can be calculated for a 2d array (it's not jagged)

Comment: I've edited my question to add more information. I don't think the second array is needed in your solution, because we can access the `1-dimensional array` by mathematics operators.

Comment: Just read the first comment of this question. Hey, maybe you're right! In case (for example): `a[0] = new int[] {1, 6, 9}` and `a[1] = new int[] {1}`, we must use the second array for indexing!

Comment: As George stated, though.. if you array really looks like this: {1,2,3,4},{1,2},{1,2,3,4,5} and fits in a 3x5 array, then you would need the indexes stored.

Comment: I'm still waiting for more answers and comments. I will mark this as answer if no better answer is given next 2 days. Sorry for the delay :)

Comment: No problem; if there is any change in the nature of the question, I'll clarify.

Comment: Sorry mate. The answer is Barber's idea. However, I still got a perfect point, because he gave me a second chance! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question properly

it's easy m8...

it's only an algorithm question.. not a programming language specific...

you can do it like this:

1. one array holds the values
2. second array holds the keys
3. try to find a workaround in the second array to know what keys you've got..

   ```
   For example:
   array_1: v0 v1 v2 null v3 v4 v5 null v6 v7 v8 null
   array_2: 0  1  2  newR 0  1  2  newR 0  1  2  newR
   ```

You can represent it in one array as well... but you need a specific algorithm to figure out when you are located on Y of the matrix.

The problem is that you won't access the data instantly from memory.. this is why there are bi-dimensional arrays

Another way:

1. keep in array 1 the values
2. keep in the second array the keys as string like in the following example:

   ```
   array1: value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
   array2: 0,0    0,1    1,0    1,1    2,0
   ```

there are a lot of algorithms but I don't think you will find better than bi-dimensional arrays...

When you look after them you will have less performance.. ofc.. unless you keep them in hashtables.. hashing 0,0 and added as key in a hashtable and add the specified value to that key. then you will look for key "0,0"...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to transform you 2-demension array (typed `RelevantType[,]`) into 2 arrays (typed `SomeTypeA[]` and `SomeTypeB[]`) without losing any information?

It's not very difficult:
Have the first array be of type `RelevantType[]`, the second one of type `int[]`, copy the content of your 2-dimensionnal array into the first one and its first indices into the second one, and you're done.

Comment: He didn't say anything about array type, so I guess I have to convert `someType[, ]` into 2 `someType[]`s, and yes, you're right about one thing: No information lost.